# Проблемы с анимацией onmousemove

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, веб-программирование

Всем здравствуйте! Учусь делать анимацию, используя реакт. Необходимо, чтобы каждая картинка "следила" за курсором, получилось только, чтобы они двигались все вместе при движении курсора по всему окну, а нужно, чтобы каждая по отдельности при движении курсора внутри своего собственного div.services_pic.
Пыталась использовать document.getElementsByClassName('services_pic') вместо window, но безуспешно. Буду благодарна объяснению, спасибо!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import img1 from "../img/services/1.svg";
import img2 from "../img/services/2.svg";
import img3 from "../img/services/3.svg";
import img4 from "../img/services/4.svg";
import img5 from "../img/services/5.svg";

class Services extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.init();
  }
  init() {
    this.state = {
      offsetX: "",
      offsetY: "",
      friction: 1 / 32,
    };
    this._mouseMove = this._mouseMove.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", this._mouseMove);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this._mouseMove);
  }
  _mouseMove(e) {
    let followX = window.innerWidth / 2 - e.clientX;
    let followY = window.innerHeight / 2 - e.clientY;

    let x = 0,
      y = 0;
    x += (-followX - x) * this.state.friction;
    y += (followY - y) * this.state.friction;
    this.setState({
      offsetX: x,
      offsetY: y,
    });
  }
  render() {
    let offset = {
      transform: `perspective(600px)
                  rotateY(${this.state.offsetX}deg)
                  rotateX(${this.state.offsetY}deg)`,
    };

    return (
      <section className="services">
        <div className="container">
          <h2 className="section_title">Сервисы и услуги</h2>
          <div className="services_wrapper">
            <div className="services_item">
              <div className="services_pic" style={offset}>
                <img className="services_image" src={img1} alt="2" />
              </div>
              <div className="services_title">
                Разработка программного обеспечения
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="services_item">
              <div className="services_pic" style={offset}>
                <img className="services_image" src={img2} alt="2" />
              </div>
              <div className="services_title">QA-решения</div>
            </div>
            <div className="services_item">
              <div className="services_pic" style={offset}>
                <img className="services_image" src={img3} alt="3" />
              </div>
              <div className="services_title">Интеграционные решения</div>
            </div>
            <div className="services_item">
              <div className="services_pic" style={offset}>
                <img className="services_image" src={img4} alt="4" />
              </div>
              <div className="services_title">Консалтинг</div>
            </div>
            <div className="services_item">
              <div className="services_pic" style={offset}>
                <img className="services_image" src={img5} alt="5" />
              </div>
              <div className="services_title">Мобильные разработки</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Services;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое: Все фото должны рендериться в отдельном компоненте. Примерно так должен выглядеть твой компонент фотографий:

```
// Компонент Services 
return (
      <section className="services">
        <div className="container">
          <h2 className="section_title">Сервисы и услуги</h2>
          <div className="services_wrapper">
            {this.state.picture.forEach(el=>  <ServiceItem _mouseMove = {this._mouseMove.bind(this)} style = {offset} key = {el.id} element = {el}/>)}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  
  

  // Компонент ServiceItem 
 
   return (<>
              <div className="services_item" onMouseMove  = {this.props._mouseMove}>
                  <div className="services_pic" style={this.props.offset}>
                      <img className="services_image" src={this.props.element.src} alt="2" />
                 </div>
                  <div className="services_title">
                      {this.props.element.title}
                  </div>
          </>        
)
```

Второе: В тег элемента добавь атрибут  `<div className="services_pic" onMouseMove  = {this._mouseMove.bind(this)}>`

Думаю что ты понял, что фотографии нужно хранить в стейте, желательно в массиве.

Comment: Забыл добавить, в стейт где хранятся фото добавь расположение которое будешь изменять в функции __mouseMove

Comment: спасибо, все поправила, но с анимацией все равно что-то не то. Видимо дело в рассчетах координат, но картинки крутятся совсем не так, как нужно. Буду очень лагодарна, если посмотришь, может, увидишь в чем ошибка.
Должно быть так: https://codepen.io/Bilgili/pen/EbZepr
а вот мой код: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-khorana-ntpki?file=/src/Components/ServiceItem.js

Comment: @daryalewy Подправил, вроде работает. Ток со значениями беда... Можешь сама поэкспериментировать) useCallback редко использую, если у тебя в этом компоненте ничего не будет изменятся кроме анимации, его можно убрать.